# Mockito when returns null when rest call parameter passed in is JSON

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a piece of code that I want to test which takes a JSON string and uses the object from the JSON string to call a method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cancel", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public ReservationCancelResponseType cancel(@RequestBody CancelReservationRequest request) {
        ReservationCancelResponseType result = null;

        for(BrandEnum brand : request.getBrands()) {
            switch(brand) {
            case BRAND_NAME:
                result = service.cancel(request);
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I am trying to call this using the following code

```
@Test
public void testCancel() throws Exception {
    ReservationCancelResponseType responseType = new ReservationCancelResponseType();

    CancelReservationRequest request = new CancelReservationRequest();
    List<BrandEnum> brands = new ArrayList<>();
    brands.add(BrandEnum.BRAND_NAME);
    request.setBrands(brands);

    String requestString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request);

    when(service.cancel(request)).thenReturn(responseType);

    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/cancel")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(requestString)
            ).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

I think the reason this is not working is because in the `when().thenReturn()` call, I am passing in an object but in the rest call I am passing in a `String` version of this object created by the `objectMapper` so these are different so I am getting `null` for the `when().thenReturn()` call

Is this correct and if so how would you suggest i resolve this?

Comment: (1) Is the instance of `service` which is used by your controller in the test flow **definitely** the same instance as you are mocking in your test?; (2) Does `CancelReservationRequest` have an implementation of `equals()`? I suspect the issue is the latter one ... you could verify this by changing `when(service.cancel(request)).thenReturn(responseType)` to `when(service.cancel(Mockito.any(CancelReservationRequest.class))).thenReturn(responseType)`. If the service.cancel() method returns your response type then you'll know the issue is with `CancelReservationRequest`'s equality check.

Comment: I have changed the `when` call to use `Mockito.any(CancelReservationRequest.cla‌​ss)` as suggested above to see if this was an issue with equality and the test works so it is an issue with that. Now that I know what I need to look at I can work on this. Thanks and if you want to put that as an answer ill accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the instance of service which is used by your controller in the test flow definitely the same instance as you are mocking in your test then the likeliest cause of the issue is `CancelReservationRequest`'s implementation of `equals()`. Either it has no `equals()` or its `equals()` implementation is returning false when Mockito attempts to compare the instance expected by your `when/then` call with the instance used inside your controller method.

You could verify this by changing ...

```
when(service.cancel(request)).thenReturn(responseType)
```

... to :

```
when(service.cancel(Mockito.any(CancelReservationRequest.cla‌ss))).thenReturn(res‌​ponseType)
```

If the `service.cancel()` method returns your response type then you'll know the issue is with `CancelReservationRequest`'s equality check. The fix for this is to implement an `equals()` method which allows Mockito to correctly compare the instance expected by your `when/then` call with the instance used inside your controller method. You could even use `Mockito.refEq()` if creating a custom `equals()` method is not a runner.