# Why Getting Empty Response when writing UnitTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am learning to write Unit Test for SpringBoot Restcontroller , wrote this and test passes

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {FhirApp.class, TestSecurityConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ObservationControllerTest {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ObservationService observationService;

    @Test
    public void createObservationResource() throws Exception {

        given(observationService.createObservation(ResourceStringProvider.observationsource()))
                .willReturn(responseDocument);

        String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(
                          ResourceStringProvider.observationsource());

        mockMvc.perform(post("/Observation")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(jsonString))
            .andExpect(status()
            .isOk());
}
```

But as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020089/getting-blank-response-in-spring-rest-controller-unit-test-cases) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691094/spring-boot-integration-test-responding-with-empty-body-mockmvc) , i am also getting empty response for response.getContentAsString() :

```
Mockito.when(observationService.createObservation(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(responseDocument);

String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ResourceStringProvider.observationsource());

MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(post("/Observation")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(jsonString))
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse();

    assertThat(response.getContentAsString())
        .isEqualTo(new ObjectMapper()
                            .writeValueAsString(responseDocument));
```

I already tried the solutions provided by them :

```
1: Using Mockito.any(String.class) 
2: webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK
3: using thenCallRealMethod instead of thenReturn(responseDocument)
```

But unfortunately it didn't work,already tried different possibilities , I also tried using MockitoJunitRunner :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {FhirApp.class, TestSecurityConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ObservationControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
private ObservationService observationService;

@Mock
private RequestFilter requestFilter;

@InjectMocks
private ObservationController observationController;

@Before
public void setup() {
    Resource resource = Utility.convertFromStringToFhirResource(Observation.class,ResourceStringProvider.observationResponse());
    responseDocument=Utility.convertFromFhirResourceToMongoInsertibleDoc(resource);

    //these line enabled for MockitoJUnitRunner only 
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(observationController)
        .setControllerAdvice(new FhirRuntimeException("Error Happened"))
        .addFilters(requestFilter)
        .build();
}

@Test
public void createObservationResource()throws Exception{
    Mockito.when(observationService.createObservation(ResourceStringProvider.observationsource())).thenReturn(responseDocument);

    String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ResourceStringProvider.observationsource());
    MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(
        post("/Observation")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(jsonString))
        .andReturn()
        .getResponse();

    assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(responseDocument));
}
```

i think since not many have went through such issues, issue isn't much talked about . What could be the reason of empty response when response status is ok?

Controller code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ObservationController {

    @Autowired
    private ObservationService observationService;


    @GetMapping("/Observation/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Document> getObservationByID(
        @RequestParam("_pretty") Optional<String> pretty,
        @PathVariable("id") String id) {
        Document resultDoc = observationService.getObservationById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resultDoc, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @PostMapping(path = "/Observation", consumes = {"application/json", "application/fhir+json"},
        produces = {"application/json", "application/fhir+json"})
    public ResponseEntity<Document> createObservationResource(@RequestBody String fhirResource) {
        Document fhirDoc = observationService.createObservation(fhirResource);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(fhirDoc,
            Utility.createHeaders(fhirDoc),
            HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    //other methods
}
```

I realized the call to post in test should be /api/Observation , but it didn't make any difference . Thanks in Advance.

Comment: and when you debug your tests, what do you find is wrong? if you have an empty result then whatever you are returning to client is empty. But you have not posted what your server side code looks like so we have no idea.

Comment: I have updated the code of controller . Actually the whole project is Spring-Boot project generated using Jhipster .

Comment: and when you debug your tests? can you verify that `Document fhirDoc` is not null.

Comment: it's probably because `ResourceStringProvider.observationsource()` creates different objects and these don't match when you use them in your mock. You can try to override the equals method.

Comment: Based on Your comments i checked using Mockito.verify() and controller itself was not getting called somehow . also  this gem https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2017/07/30/guide-spring-boot-controller-tests/  helped a lot.

Answer (score -2):

Posting the complete answer alongwith imports here so that it will help someone (actually we don't require any annotation above and it is one way to run it , during my findings i came accross this [post](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/) which helps in solving design issue which may occur if you go ahead with @InjectMocks approach)

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;

import com.comitemd.emr.datalayer.fhir.service.ObservationService;
import com.comitemd.emr.datalayer.fhir.utility.ResourceStringProvider;
import com.comitemd.emr.datalayer.fhir.utility.Utility;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Observation;
import org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Resource;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

//@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ObservationControllerStandaloneTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Mock
    private ObservationService observationService;
    @InjectMocks
    private ObservationController observationController;

    private Document responseDocument;
    @Before
    public void setup() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);// enable this or MockitoJUnitRunner.class
        Resource resource = Utility
            .convertFromStringToFhirResource(Observation.class, ResourceStringProvider.observationResponse());
         responseDocument=Utility.convertFromFhirResourceToMongoInsertibleDoc(resource);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(observationController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void createObservationResource()throws Exception{
        Mockito.when(observationService.createObservation(ResourceStringProvider.observationsource()))
            .thenReturn(responseDocument);

        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(
            post("/api/Observation")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(ResourceStringProvider.observationsource()))
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse();

        verify(observationService, times(1)).createObservation(Mockito.any());
        assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(responseDocument));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not Sure why a working program have been downvoted?